# CentOS Apache can't access to file in home dir

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos, file-permissions

I have a problem I couldn't solve so far. I'm using CentOS which provides the apache web files in `/var/www/html/`. Now I got some data, which are loaded by another user, to (let's say) `/home/user1/files/`.

Every time I want to access those files I get permission denied. Those files and directories (evene parent til root) can be read. (`chmod -R o+r /home`)
But I still get this error, as next step I've created a symlink:
`/var/www/html/ -> /home/user1/files` but still the same error.

Those are files which are updated every day, so I can't copy them over, and a cronjob would be bad because I need them by their time. Copying creats a new inode. (need always latest file).

I would really appreciate an idea.

yadbo

Answer (score 0):

Apache user and group is different from any system user, so file permisions by default doesn't allow someone from another id and another group to read it.

You should either add www-data (or the group of your default apache user) to the group of users who can read the file OR (NEVER DO THIS) let anyone be able to read those files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already added apache to the group of the other user.